# How do I auto increment numbers in XML code?

Tags: xml, generator, increment

I have some XML code that must be printed out hundreds of times but using different values on each line. I want to know if there is either an auto generator online that I can use, or I will have to create a program that does it. (optimistic for me).

The XML:

```
 <INSTANCE>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <START>0</START>
    <END>10</END>
    <CODE>00:00:10</CODE>
</INSTANCE>

<INSTANCE>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <START>10</START>
    <END>20</END>
    <CODE>00:00:20</CODE>
</INSTANCE>
```

I need this until the ID is 1080. What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: You can do this in Excel, just make one column with the numbers and the next column with the formula to produce the XML with the corresponding number.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Globals
var ID = 0;
var start =0;
var end =10;
var time = "00:00:00";
var minutes;
var seconds;
var theTime;
var easyReadVar = false;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var timeCounter=0;

function Go(){
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<file>\n";
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<ALL_INSTANCES>\n";
    for (i=1; i <= 1080; i++){
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<instance>\n";
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<ID>" + i + "</ID>\n";
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<start>" + start + "</start>\n";
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<end>" + end + "</end>\n";
        timeString();
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "<code>" + theTime + "</code>\n";
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "</instance>\n";
        if (easyReadVar == true){document.getElementById("mainDiv").value += "\n";}
        start = start + 10;
        end = end + 10;         
    }
}

function timeString(){
    time = end;
    if (time < 60){     
        theTime = "00:00:" + time;
    }
    else if (time >= 60 && time < 3600){
        minutes = time / 60;
        minutes  =  Math.trunc( minutes );
        //conditioner - if minutes is single digit, place a zero before
        if (minutes <10){minutes = "0" + minutes}       
        seconds = time - (minutes * 60);
        //conditioner - if seconds is single digit, place a zero before
        if (seconds <10){seconds = "0" + seconds}       
        theTime = "00:" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    else if (time >= 3600){
        hours = (time / 60) / 60;
        hours  =  Math.trunc( hours );      
        minutes = time - (hours * 60) *60;
        minutes = minutes / 60;
        minutes = Math.trunc(minutes);
        seconds = time - (((hours * 60) * 60) + ((minutes * 60) ));     
        //conditioner - if hours is single digit, place a zero before
        if (hours <10){hours = "0" + hours}             
        //conditioner - if minutes is single digit, place a zero before
        if (minutes <10){minutes = "0" + minutes}
        //conditioner - if second is single digit, place a zero before
        if (seconds <10){seconds = "0" + seconds}
        theTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;        
    }   
}

function easyRead(){
    //The easy reader version - basically flags into main algo to place a return line
    resetAllVars();
    easyReadVar = true;
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").value = "";
    Go();
}

function resetAllVars(){
//This is necessary as otherwise variables continue with current values
ID = 0;
start =0;
end =10;
time = "00:00:00";
minutes = 0;
seconds = 0;
theTime = 0;    
}

function splash(){
    /*Display splash screen on startup (splashDiv)*/
    /*THIS SHOULD IDEALLY BE DONE USING JS WINDOW SIZE DETECTION*/
    if (timeCounter < 2){
    window.document.getElementById("splashDiv").innerHTML = "<img src=\"logo.png\" style=\"width:300px; margin-top: " + (windowHeight /2 - (117/2)) + "px;\">";
    window.document.getElementById('wideDiv').style.display = "none";
    }
    if (timeCounter >= 4){
        window.document.getElementById('splashDiv').style.display = "none";
        window.document.getElementById('wideDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
    /*Display for 3 or 2 seconds*/
    /*Hide splash screen - similar to menu disappear - display: none;*/ 
}


function timeTicker(){
    setInterval(function(){ splash(); }, 1);
    setInterval(function(){ timeCounter; timeCounter++; }, 1000);   
}
```